# Spring boot JNDI datasource lookup failure - Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:"

Tags: datasource, war, jndi, spring-boot, websphere-8

I have setup a spring boot (v 1.1.9) application to deploy as a WAR file. And I'm trying to integrate this web application with an existing data service module (added as a maven dependency).

Environment trying to deploy: **WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.4**

The issue I'm facing is an application start-up failure when try to look-up a JNDI dataSource (**jdbc/fileUploadDS**) as below within the dependent data service module.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class JndiDataConfig implements DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
          Context ctx = new InitialContext();
          return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/fileUploadDS");
    }

}
```

My Spring Boot configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "au.com.aiaa.fileupload.data.*", "demo" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<SampleApplication> applicationClass = SampleApplication.class;

    @Bean
    public static Properties fileUploadJndiProperties() throws NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiFactoryBean.setJndiName("props/FileUploadProperties");
        jndiFactoryBean.setExpectedType(Properties.class);
        jndiFactoryBean.setLookupOnStartup(true);
        jndiFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (Properties) jndiFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

}
```

Note that I'm able to lookup props/FileUploadProperties successfully. But failing to do the same for a datasource.

My doubt is it is trying to load a **EmbeddedWebApplicationContext** which is not what I want.

**The stack trace is:**

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource au.com.aiaa.fileupload.data.dao.configuration.JndiDataConfig.dataSource() throws javax.naming.NamingException] threw exception; nested exception is **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:".**
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at **org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)**
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)


..................

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource au.com.aiaa.fileupload.data.dao.configuration.JndiDataConfig.dataSource() throws javax.naming.NamingException] threw exception; nested exception is **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:".**
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
        ... 132 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/jdbc not found in context "java:".
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1970)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1377)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1220)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1142)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
        at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
        at au.com.aiaa.fileupload.data.dao.configuration.JndiDataConfig.dataSource(JndiDataConfig.java:41)
        at au.com.aiaa.fileupload.data.dao.configuration.JndiDataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8001dbbe.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)
        at au.com.aiaa.fileupload.data.dao.configuration.JndiDataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8001dbbe$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3c9e0518.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
        at au.com.aiaa.fileupload.data.dao.configuration.JndiDataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8001dbbe.dataSource(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
```

What am I missing here? Even when I try to explicitly define the dataSource bean method in SampleApplication.java like below it fails with the same error.

```
@Bean
    public static DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiFactoryBean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/fileUploadDS");
        jndiFactoryBean.setExpectedType(DataSource.class);
        jndiFactoryBean.setLookupOnStartup(true);
        jndiFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) jndiFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

I referred [this](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi) and it says we need to set enableNaming() on servlet container? Can I do something similar for non-embedded web application context? Or is it purely a WAS 8.5 issue??

Comment: Have you tried the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` WITHOUT the `java:comp/env/` part?

Comment: You need to have resource reference with `jdbc/fileUploadDS` name in your `web.xml`. And make sure it is bound to actual datasource name during installation or via `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks @Gas it works. I added the resource-ref in web.xml and bound the resource reference to actual datasource while installation in WAS admin console. But how do I achieve the same without a web.xml in my spring boot application? I read [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) how to replace <servlet>, <servlet-mapping> or <filter>, <filter-mapping> within spring boot configuration class extending SpringBootServletInitializer. Is there any equivalent for <resource-ref> as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have resource reference with `jdbc/fileUploadDS` name in your `web.xml`. And make sure it is bound to actual datasource name during installation or via `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file.

Definition in `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description />
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/fileUploadDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

If you dont want to use `web.xml`, then in normal Java EE app you could just add in web component (servlet, filter) the following class annotation:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/fileUploadDS", type=javax.sql.DataSource.class, lookup="jdbc/fileUploadDS")
```

but I'm not Spring-boot expert, so don't know, if it will work or is possible there.

Comment: As I mentioned, adding the <resource-ref> is the only option which suits my requirement as I do not need to lookup the dataSource within the spring boot application but within an external dependency. So even if I get @Resource working, it is not what I'm after.

Comment: @DinushaKariyawasam Ok. BTW the `@Resource` at the **class** level has the same functionality as <resource-ref> in `web.xml`. When application is installed, classes are scanned for annotations and merged web.xml is created. You can see merged deployment descriptor via admin console.

Comment: You're correct!  This how i did it in Java 6 / JEE 5  
@Resource(name = "jdbc/fileUploadDS",type = javax.sql.DataSource.class)
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

}   I referred to '**Declaring Resource References**' section in [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html#bnaew) and we can @Resource annotate any **Web Components That Accept Resource Injections**

Answer (score 3):

I am able to connect my Spring-Boot application (deployed in Websphere Application Server 9) to WAS datasource.
The following code worked for me, for connecting to DataSource:

```
@Bean(name = "WASDataSource")
public DataSource WASDataSource() throws Exception {        
JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("DSNAME");
}   

@Bean(name = "WASDataSourceJdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate_WASDS(@Qualifier("WASDataSource")
DataSource dsDB2) {
return new JdbcTemplate(dsDB2);
}
```

Note: The name of Datasource "DSNAME" is the name which appears on the UI of Websphere console.
You can see that via -> Select Resources > JDBC > Data Sources.

Then I created jdbc template:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("WASDataSourceJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate db2WASTemplate;`
```

And running query using the query method works fine :
    db2WASTemplate.query()

I did not create any Web.xml or ibm-web-bnd.xml files

Answer (score 2):

I just configured spring boot with my custom datasource as follows:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

and inside the application.properties file I defined all datasource settings as usual

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= ***
spring.datasource.url= ***
spring.datasource.username= ***
spring.datasource.password= ***
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/myDB
```

It works nicely with @SpringBootApplication with all other default settings

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. I don't know how to define  tag in spring boot since there is no web.xml file in the spring boot.

So far what I came to know that we have to define it in the application file from where we start our spring application. I think we need to use this method to set the Datasource:

```
  @Bean(destroyMethod="")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.mine")
  public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
      JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
      return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:jdbc/configurationFile");
  }
```