# JNDI configuration with spring boot with WebSphere 9.0.0.7

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, jndi, ear

I have added spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/DB_Name
 property in application.properties file, datasource not created.

I want to use that datasoure with spring boot 2.0.3, spring boot data jpa(hibernate),websphere. Need to use the jparepository for CURD operations.

I have seen the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479263/spring-boot-jndi-datasource-lookup-failure-name-comp-env-jdbc-not-found-in-con/27495108). But we don't have web.xml in spring boot to add resource reference. So can't follow that answer. How can I achieve the jparepository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add the below property in application.properties

> spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/yourjndiname

In SpringApplication.java class where is our spring boot main method exist.Below code generates the datasource for us.

```
@Autowired
    private Environment env;
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.jndi-name"));
    }
```

And one more thing
If you want access to your table in  schema level mention the schema name in @Table(schema = "DB_SCHEMA",name = "DB_TABLE")